# Can I install/reference packages from within an fsx file?

Tags: f#, f#-scripting

I'm trying to find a simple solution that isn't so much manual work to reference packages. inside a .fsx file.

- `LinqPad 4` lets me simply add nuget packages

  - no intellisense or autocompletion
  - deletes package after download for certain types of packages ([templatus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Templatus/) for example)
- `LinqPad 5 beta` lets me add nuget packages

  - deletes package after download for certain types of packages ([templatus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Templatus/) for example)
  - with frequent failures (intellisense and [compilation](http://forum.linqpad.net/discussion/968/missing-method-exceptions?new=1))
- `VS2015` doesn't let you download/install packages for an fsx file (only into projects)
- `VSCode` doesn't let you download/install nuget or paket packages for an fsx file.

So I wind up having to use .fsx in VS2015, while using linqpad to get packages downloaded (which still fails for packages like templatus where it downloads an exe not a dll). Then I have I can reference them as

```
#I @"..\LINQPad\NuGet.FW46\FParsec\FParsec.1.0.2\lib\net40-client\" // references AppData\local\ ...  since . is %localappdata%\TEMP
```

- doesn't match up with the relative pathing for intellisense/autocompletion engine in VSCode so I can't remove VS from the equation.
- doesn't work outside of a machine that already has that package in that location
- wind up doing a [bunch of code](https://github.com/ImaginaryDevelopment/LinqPad/blob/master/LINQPad%20Queries/Roslyn/convert%20INotifyClass%20to%20F%23.fsx#L6-L93) that doesn't span .fsx files very well and has to be worked out per package reference

I don't want to create a project. I have a ton of individual scripts that are to be individually maintained and usable by others on-demand.

**Is there an IDE (or fix/extension for one of these mentioned) that will give me intellisense, autocomplete, and package management for F# .fsx files that can work easily from user to user, machine to machine?**

Comment: this should probably be linked in case something like this is actually added to fsc/fsi  https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/837

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[The Ionide plugins](http://ionide.io/) for [VsCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and [Atom](https://atom.io/) have the functionality you're looking for

### VsCode Instructions

Use the command palette to install the Ionide extensions [ionide-fsharp](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/Ionide.Ionide-fsharp) and [ionide-paket](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/Ionide.Ionide-Paket)

[image]

You'll need to add your F# installation to your `PATH`
([on windows Rapid Enivornment Editor](http://www.rapidee.com/en/about) is my goto for `PATH` editing)

For F# 4.0 add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.0\Framework\v4.0`

Open the work folder that will hold your `.fsx` files

Executing paket commands through the command palette will be your primary interface for working with nuget packages

[image]

make a new `.fsx` file, (I recommend using the [Advanced New File](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/dkundel.vscode-new-file) extension over the standard VsCode method)

The first step is to run `paket init` which is necessary to use paket to manage your packages

[image]

If you click the `open` button on the notification popups you can view the the output from paket in a side panel

[image]

After using the `add nuget package` command and entering `extcore`for the package you should see the work tree
updated to

[image]

Then all you need to do is reference the package in the script and you'll get the auto-completion you're looking for

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 14):

As of F# 5.0 you can now use the `#r "nuget: Package"` ([ref](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-f-5/#package-references-in-f-scripts)):

```ml
#r "nuget: Newtonsoft.Json"
// Optionally, specify a version explicitly
// #r "nuget: Newtonsoft.Json,11.0.1"

open Newtonsoft.Json

let o = {| X = 2; Y = "Hello" |}

printfn "%s" (JsonConvert.SerializeObject o)
```